# create procedures in different schema without schema name and without altering search_path

Tags: postgresql

I have a list of procedures where 25% of procedures need to be compiled in a particular schema likewise for the rest of procedures, totally there are 5 schemas.

No procedure will exist in more than one schema.

While creating/compiling, I cannot use the schema prefix before the procedure names. The procedure can have database objects from different schemas.
As of now, I am required to alter the `search_path` every time when compiling a procedure(based on which schema it needs to reside).

Is there any easier alternate to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a function dependent on the `search_path` in the current session sounds fragile.

How about using dynamic SQL?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE do_something(p_schema text)
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   old_search_path text;
BEGIN
   old_search_path := current_setting('search_path');
   EXECUTE format('SET LOCAL search_path = %I', p_schema);
   /* so something */
   EXECUTE format('SET LOCAL search_path = %s', old_search_path);
END;$$;
```

Comment: Ok, I meant "creating a function".

Comment: That makes more sense. Know, then, that the setting of `search_path` when you create the function is irrelevant. It is the setting when you call the function that matters.